# Extract jinja syntax from html in php

Tags: php, html, regex, laravel

i am trying to extract jinja syntax from html and convert it in actual tag so that i can manipulate it on frontend.
Till now i tried  `preg_replace_callback`
to get the data but its only efficient to get small string but not big like data inside conditional phrases like

```
        <span>{% if is_vardiya %}</span><span style="font-size: 10pt"> </span>
      </p>
      <p style="margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt; text-align: justify">
        <span style="-aw-import: ignore">&#xa0;</span>
      </p>
      <p
        style="
          margin-top: 0pt;
          margin-bottom: 0pt;
          text-align: justify;
          font-size: 12pt;
        "
      >
        <span
          >Çalışan.
        </span>
      </p>
      <p
        style="
          margin-top: 0pt;
          margin-bottom: 0pt;
          text-align: justify;
          font-size: 12pt;
        "
      >
        <span>{% endif %}</span>
```

.Here i want to get data inside `{% if is_vardiya %}` and `{% endif %}`  and i also need to deal with nested `if` blocks. I know regex is not a good approach to deal with html manipulation and extraction but can someone redirect me in more good and effective approach to dela with this problem.

i tried to use `preg_replace_callback` like this

```
        $html = preg_replace_callback(
            '/{%\s*(p if|if)\s*(?:\w+)(?:[\w=!\'. ]*)\s*%}([\w\s+<\/>="-:;])*(?:{%\s*(p if|if)\s*(?:\w+)(?:[\w=!\'. ]*)\s*%}[\w\s+<\/>="-:;]*(?:{%\s*else\s*%}[\w\s+<\/>="-:;]*)*{%\s*(p endif|endif)\s*%}([\w\s+<\/>="-:;])*|(?R))*([\w\s+<\/>="-:;])*(?:{%\s*else\s*%}[\w\s+<\/>="-:;]+)*{%\s*(p endif|endif)\s*%}/',
            function ($matches) {
                $matches[0] = preg_replace('/\\r/', '', $matches[0]);
                $matches[0] = preg_replace('/\\n/', '', $matches[0]);
                preg_match_all('/{%\s*(p if|if)\s*(?:\w+)(?:[\w=!\'. ]*)\s*%}([\w\s+<\/>="-:;])*{%\s*(p endif|endif)\s*%}/', $matches[0], $subconditions,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
                if(count($subconditions[0])>0) {
                    $allSubconditions = $subconditions[0];
                    if($allSubconditions[0][1] != 0) {
                        // to-do : create recursive function to support infinite if inside if
                        foreach ($allSubconditions as $condition) {
                            $subconditionString = $this->subconditionExpression($condition[0]);
                            $matches[0] = str_replace($condition[0], $subconditionString, $matches[0]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return $this->createMainConditionExpression($matches[0]);
            },
            $html
        );
```